# "Username/client id combination not found" error trying to verify updated email address

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement a flow for the user to change their email address in cognito (without changing their password). In the default pool configuration, it's possible to update the email address without verifying the new one which is obviously a security hole so I have enabled the setting "Keep original attribute value active when an update is pending" for the email address field.

Now, after updating the email address, the user receives a verification code to the new email address exactly as expected. Before entering the verification code, they can continue to log in using the old email address but not the new one, which also seems sensible.

However when trying to apply the verification code to the new email address, it returns an error "UserNotFoundException: Username/client id combination not found"

Something that may be completely unrelated: in the page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html it says

> Remember that users require verified contact information to: ...
>
> ...Sign in by using an email address or phone number as an alias

However I've found that you can sign in using an unverified email address without any problem